# Better, more efficient redirecting

Tags: redirect

I'm working on fairly large corporate site and the redirects are starting to build up. It's going to get even more numerous as we are going to unpublish all blog, news and pr posts older than two years. The goal is to redirect all expired posts to respective archive pages (IE: /news/this-is-the-post > /news).

I'm wondering two things here...

- How many redirects is too many?
- Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: "How many redirects is too many?" - do you mean in .htaccess? Or are you configuring these in WordPress itself?

Comment: "How many redirects is too many?" is more a general question, regardless of platform or method for handling redirects. For the site in question, it's on Nginx and we use the hosting platform's redirect feature.

Comment: Well I was trying to check you meant redirect rules configured at the server end (as opposed to 'how long a sequence of redirects to get the viewer to the right page is too long?'), and get some idea how your were configuring this. In which case assuming your web server loads them in a sensible way to check them efficiently - which I'd hope they all would - this is probably just how large are you happy that your configuration files are, and at what point it becomes difficult for you to manage.